# Extract column names from sql create table without datatype - Regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

Hi I am trying to get the column names from a Create table in Java script, here is an example text, the intention is to get the only the column names `u_login_id`, `sys_id`,'`temp_id`

```
UNIQUE KEY `index8` (`u_login_id`(255),sys_id,temoid),shouldnot appear text

UNIQUE KEY `index8` (sys_id,`u_login_id`(255),temp_id),shouldnot appear text

UNIQUE KEY `index8` (`sys_id`),shouldnot appear text

UNIQUE KEY `index8` (sys_id`,temp_id)
```

I have tried this and it gives me only the fist column names.
`` UNIQUE KEY\s+`?\w+`?\s?\(\s?(`?\w+`?) ``

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: To handle this requirement in the general case, you need a parser.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I thought about it and it appears to need more than 1 step. Replace all text which are not within () and parse the column names into an array.